# C++ - what type of storage duration do local pointer variables in a function have and where are they stored?

Tags: c++

I'm looking the types of storage duration in C++ from [Storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration).

I'm just wondering which type of storage duration local pointer variables in a function have, cause non-static local variables in a function will be destoried when the block ends. But this doesn't apply to the pointers (it's `xPtr` in the case). They will still exist until the program ends, although we cannot touch it again.

> ***automatic*** storage duration. The storage for the object is allocated at the beginning of the enclosing code block and deallocated
>   at the end. All local objects have this storage duration, except those
>   declared static, extern or thread_local.
>
> ***static*** storage duration. The storage for the object is allocated when
>   the program begins and deallocated when the program ends. Only one
>   instance of the object exists. All objects declared at namespace scope
>   (including global namespace) have this storage duration, plus those
>   declared with static or extern. See Non-local variables and Static
>   local variables for details on initialization of objects with this
>   storage duration.

My other question is that, Why did the system allocate the same memory address `0x00000041C69EF754` which was still pointed by `xPtr` to the temporary variable `x` when the second time it entered the function.

```
void localPointer()
{
    int x = 10; 
    static int* xPtr = &x; // 0x00000041C69EF754 - 0a 00 00 00 (data the address contains)
    std::cout << "end of function" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    // first enter
    localPointer();

    /* 
        the address 0x00000041C69EF754 and its value still 
        exsit out of the scope of the function localPointer
    */
    std::cout << "-----------------------------------------" << std::endl;

    // second enter
    localPointer();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you not like the part about `"automatic storage duration.... All local objects have this storage duration, except those declared static, extern or thread_local."` (when you declare something `static` there is only one in that translation unit)

Comment: Nothing is “occupied” by a pointer, it just points to it. Its own memory location is kept static because you told it to be, but I assume you’re looking at the value in the pointer, which isn’t its address. Why wouldn’t the system use the same address in the stack for the same function in the same situation?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yeah I noticed that. That's why I was wondering, a pointer declared witout the `static` keyword can live out of the scope

Comment: Correction, if what the pointer points to is of allocated type, or exists in its own right outside of the scope then any pointer pointing to it will still be valid. Remember, a pointer is simply a normal variable that holds the *address of* something else as its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pointer is also a normal static variable; it's the *value* of the pointers that is dynamic when they are created with new.

In your example the pointer keeps pointing to a local stack variable that is not changed because the same stack is recreated when you enter the function.

Try calling this function from another level so the RSP value changes and see what happens. For example, create another function then call this function from it.

Comment: as the pointer is a normal static variable , so there is no difference between `int* xPtr = &x` and `static int* xPtr = &x` in the function. Can I understand in this way?

Comment: No. It's not the same. The second one initializes only once and will remain with the same value no matter what the &x happens to be.

Answer (score 1):

Since x is on the stack, the address of x is an address in the call stack.  If you try to access that address after the function exits, you might get something, but it might not be what you expect.  You've got a pointer, it's just a number.  This doesn't mean it's a valid address.

If you call `localPointer` from another function, then you will see it point to different data:

```cpp
void localPointer () {
    int x = 7;
    static int* ptr = &x;

    std::cout << " ptr = " << ptr << ", *ptr = " << *ptr 
              << ", x = " << x << ", &x = " << &x << std::endl;
}
void otherFunction() {
    int y = 8;
    std::cout << " &y = " << &y << std::endl;
    localPointer();
}
int main()
{
    localPointer();
    otherFunction();
    localPointer();
}
```

Sample output:

```
 ptr = 0x7ffd8794f13c, *ptr = 7, x = 7, &x = 0x7ffd8794f13c
 &y = 0x7ffd8794f13c
 ptr = 0x7ffd8794f13c, *ptr = 8, x = 7, &x = 0x7ffd8794f11c
 ptr = 0x7ffd8794f13c, *ptr = 7, x = 7, &x = 0x7ffd8794f13c
```

The static keyword means that this variable is only initialized once, the first time the function is called, and it persists for the duration of the program, or unless you explicitly change it.

I think you might want to clarify what it is that you want to know.  It's not a very standard practice to store the address of a local variable in a static - unless you're trying to win an obfuscated c++ competition.

Comment: It's important to note that accessing `*ptr` in the second and later calls to `localPointer()` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @DanielSchepler - indeed, which is why I said "you might get something, but it might not be what you expect"

Comment: I'm wondering why the value of `ptr` from the second call was `8`. I know variables declared with the `static` sepcifier are only initialized once, but it doesn't mean they cannot be assigned values again, from the third call it was 7 again. I don't understand why it was 8 instead of 7 from the second call. I think it should stick with 7 cause it has `static` keyword.

Comment: ptr is an address on the stack.  When you call localPointer the first time, ptr gets the addess of x in that function - it's a variable on the stack.  When calling localPointer from otherFunction, the variable y is in the location on the stack that x was before.  If you had a recursive call, ie localPointer calls localPointer, you woulld have multiple x variables - but still only one ptr.